# How to correctly read column from file when first element is empty

Tags: io, julia

I have a data file `data.txt`

```
  a  
5 b 
3 c 7
```

which I would like to load and have as

```
 julia> loaded_data
3×3 Matrix{Any}:
 ""   "a"  ""
 5  "b"  ""
 3  "c"  7
```

but it is unclear to me how to do this. Trying `readdlm`

```
julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> readdlm("data.txt")
3×3 Matrix{Any}:
  "a"  ""    ""
 5     "b"   ""
 3     "c"  7
```

does not correctly identify the first element of the first column as empty space, and instead reads `"a"` as the first element (which of course makes sense that it would). The closest I think I've gotten to what I want is using `readlines`

```
julia> readlines("data.txt")
3-element Vector{String}:
 "  a  "
 "5 b "
 "3 c 7"
```

but from here I'm not sure how to proceed. I can grab one of the rows with all the columns and `split` it, but not sure how that helps me identify the empty elements in other rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem may have many edge cases to clarify.

Here is a longer option than the other answer, but perhaps better suited to tweak for the edge cases:

```
function splittable(d)
    # find all non-space locations
    t = sort(union(findall.(!isspace, d)...))
    # find initial indices of fields
    tt = t[vcat(1,findall(diff(t).!=1).+1)]
    # prepare ranges to extract fields
    tr = [tt[i]:tt[i+1]-1 for i in 1:length(tt)-1]
    # extract substrings
    vs = map(s -> strip.(vcat([s[intersect(r,eachindex(s))] for r in tr],
                              tt[end]<=length(s) ? s[tt[end]:end] : "")), d)
    # fit substrings into matrix
    L = maximum(length.(vs))
    String.([j <= length(vs[i]) ? vs[i][j] : "" 
      for i in 1:length(vs), j in 1:L])
end
```

And:

```
julia> d = readlines("data.txt")
3-element Vector{String}:
 "  a  "
 "5 b "
 "3 c 7"

julia> dd = splittable(d)
3×3 Matrix{String}:
 ""   "a"  ""
 "5"  "b"  ""
 "3"  "c"  "7"
```

To get the partial parsing effect:

```
function parsewhatmay(m)
    M = tryparse.(Int, m)
    map((x,y)->isnothing(x) ? y : x, M, m)
end
```

and now:

```
julia> parsewhatmay(dd)
3×3 Matrix{Any}:
  ""  "a"   ""
 5    "b"   ""
 3    "c"  7
```

Comment: I like the compactness of the other solutions, but this one was the only one that worked "out of the box" for my more complex inputs. Thanks!

Edit: your `splittable` function was the key to my problem!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a possibility:

```
cnv(s) = (length(s) > 0 && all(isdigit, s)) ? parse(Int, s) : s

cnv.(stack(split.(replace.(eachline("data.txt"),"  "=>" "), " "), dims=1))
```

Comment: I really like this solution because it's a very compact way to solve the mwe I provided. But for bigger input files that may contain multiple adjacent empty elements per row, it's a bit non-trivial to generalize this (different spacing requirements per input).

Answer (score 6):

If the contents of the columns are sufficiently distinguishable to make the parsing uniquely defined, I'd use a regex on each line:

```
julia> lines
3-element Vector{String}:
 "  a  "
 "5 b "
 "3 c 7"

julia> [match(r"\s*(\d*)\s*([a-z]*)\s*(\d*)", s).captures for s in lines]
3-element Vector{Vector{Union{Nothing, SubString{String}}}}:
 ["", "a", ""]
 ["5", "b", ""]
 ["3", "c", "7"]
```

You can then proceed to parse and concatenate as you wish, e.g.

```
julia> mapreduce(vcat, lines) do line
           x, y, z = match(r"\s*(\d*)\s*([a-z]*)\s*(\d*)", line).captures
           [tryparse(Int, x) y tryparse(Int, z)]
       end
3×3 Matrix{Any}:
  nothing  "a"   nothing
 5         "b"   nothing
 3         "c"  7
```

In Julia 1.9, I think you should be able to write this as

```
stack(lines; dims=1) do line
    x, y, z = match(r"\s*(\d*)\s*([a-z]*)\s*(\d*)", line).captures
    (tryparse(Int, x), y, tryparse(Int, z))
end
```

Comment: I really thought I was going to get this answer to work but I just spent too much time figuring out how to generate the appropriate regex for more general inputs with a broader set of elements (to no avail). I'm convinced with enough time I could get it down, but I'm simply not too experienced with regex. I definitely want to spend more time generalizing this solution.